# Hiera isn't resolving Facts

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm having some trouble with Puppet and Hiera, in that Hiera seems to not be using the facts I ask for in the templates.

I have a `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml` file, with a simple sample hierarchy in it:

```
---
version: 5

defaults:
  datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/%{::environment}/hieradata"
  data_hash: yaml_data

hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-node data"
    path: "nodes/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"

  - name: "Per-OS defaults"
    path: "os/%{facts.os.family}.yaml"

  - name: "Common data"
    path: "common.yaml"
```

I then have a puppet agent which has run and sent it's facts to Puppet. When I test a lookup on it, the variables all expand out to empty strings:

```
> puppet lookup profiles --environment production --node puppet.example.local --explain

Searching for "lookup_options"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml"
    Merge strategy hash
      Hierarchy entry "Per-node data"
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/nodes/test-.yaml"
          Original path: "nodes/test-%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
          Path not found
      Hierarchy entry "Per-OS defaults"
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/os/.yaml"
          Original path: "os/%{facts.os.family}.yaml"
          Path not found
      Hierarchy entry "Common data"
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml"
          Original path: "common.yaml"
          No such key: "lookup_options"
Searching for "profiles"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml"
    Hierarchy entry "Per-node data"
      Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/nodes/.yaml"
        Original path: "nodes/test-%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
        Path not found
    Hierarchy entry "Per-OS defaults"
      Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/os/.yaml"
        Original path: "os/%{facts.os.family}.yaml"
        Path not found
    Hierarchy entry "Common data"
      Path "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml"
        Original path: "common.yaml"
        No such key: "profiles"
Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'profiles'
```

The value isn't found, but I figure that's irrelevant because it isn't even looking for any real files, that are all showing as `nodes/.yaml` and `os/.yaml`.

If I run the command again with `--debug`, I can see a dump of information about the node that includes the facts:

```
Debug: Facter: fact "osfamily" has resolved to "RedHat".
...
Debug: Facter: fact "os" has resolved to {
  architecture => "x86_64",
  family => "RedHat",
  hardware => "x86_64",
  name => "CentOS",
  release => {
    full => "7.4.1708",
    major => "7",
    minor => "4"
  },
```

Puppet: 5.4.0

Comment: This is Facter 3.x?

Comment: @MattSchuchard `facter --version` says 3.10.0.

Comment: You are not specifying any facts on the command line.  The `puppet lookup` command will obtain and use the most recent facts for the specified node *if they are recorded in puppetdb and the command is run on a node that has access*.  It does not collect facts automatically as `puppet agent` or `puppet apply` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Have your facts file specified in the following path

```
/etc/facter/facts.d/${your_component_facts}.sh
```

and give required permissions:

```
chmod +x /etc/facter/facts.d/${your_component_facts}.sh
```